# Create Horizontal List based on certain variable in Google Sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a thousand coordinates based on Places Name, for example, as in picture

[image: Example]

I have to create a polygon from coordinates separated by comma based on Places Name. My formula example in row E1.
But it will be tiring if I have to type the formula one by one while I have to determine Latitude Longitude based on the Places

Are there the fastest way to solve while I can create a list of coordinates separated by comma based on a variable (Places Name) in column A?

Comment: One possibility would be to create a pivot table, and then specify that it calculates an array for each change in column A?

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(
 IF(D2:D<>"", {A2:A&"♠", D2:D&","}, ),
 "select max(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1")
 ,,999^99)), "♠")), ",$", ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks @player0, it solves entire problems 
Thank you so much

Would you explain the formula :)

Comment: sure, it creates a pivot table of values in column A.  then we use TRANSPOSE to flip the table by 90° and marge D values. to get rid of weird spaces we use TRIM and as a final touch, we use REGEXREPLACE to remove the comma after last coordinate